# Why can I not get a field's datetime value from queryset?

Tags: django, django-models

This may sounds stupid but has bugged me for a while. I have this model:

```
class LastVisited(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    lastvisited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to get `lastvisited` in order to compare it with `datetime.now()`.

So when I query it:

```
lastv = LastVisited.objects.filter(topic_id=t.id, user_id=request.user.id)
print 'lastv\n', lastv
print 'lastv date \n',  lastv.lastvisited
```

I get

```
[<LastVisitedTopic: LastVisitedTopic object>]
```

but the `lastv.lastvisited` is empty.

I tried to get values from queryset instead:

```
lastv = LastVisited.objects.filter(topic_id=t.id, user_id=request.user.id).values('lastvisited')
```

It prints out:

```
[{'lastvisited': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 22, 18, 58, 15, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

So the field is not empty but it is not accessible through usual `.field` method.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try `lastv[0].lastvisited ` if you're using `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `LastVisited.objects.filter`, that would give you a queryset. Queryset doesn't have `lastvisited` attribute. Do `LastVisited.objects.get` instead.

Comment: Strangely, using `GET` also, `lastv.lastvisited` does not print out anything.

Comment: It should work. Are you looking at the right `print` statement? You got the print output as `LastVisitedTopic` instance, but you are querying for `LastVisited` model. Maybe there's something else that prints as well.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. It was a mistake in reading print output.